# android manifest is no well formed

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest, adt

Since i upgraded to ADT 20, i've been trying to create new Android project, but the same thing happen every time : The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed. And i've got another error in my main activity. R is not generated.

<<<<<<< Original

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</application>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</application>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Test"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.testphonegap.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
<application>
    <activity android:name=".Test"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

=======

```
<application>
    <activity android:name=".Test"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="android.app.ListActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

> > > > > > > Added

Comment: The ``R.java`` won't be generated as long as you have errors in your project. Consider pasting your ``AndroidManifest.xml`` for us to view it.

Comment: Are that different projects? If true I think there are some parts missing.

Comment: set min sdk version as 8 . Clean the project from Project Clean!! and how many times u added application in manifest

Comment: i don't know it was generated automatically.

Comment: @Tsunaze post your final(latest) manifest.xml file.

Comment: Okay, i think i know what happen. So the first time i wanted to create this new project, i missed something, so i deleted it from Eclipse, and from my computer, i started again, without exiting Eclipse, so it build in top of the former AndroidManifest.xml (even if it was deleted). So i deleted all, made a clean, and reboot Eclipse, and know it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i think i know what happen. So the first time i wanted to create this new project, i missed something, so i deleted it from Eclipse, and from my computer, i started again, without exiting Eclipse, so it build in top of the former AndroidManifest.xml (even if it was deleted). So i deleted all, made a clean, and reboot Eclipse, and know it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As my knowledge you have to upgrade to ADT 20.0.1